# How to retrieve PROJECTION value for a map?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, c++

I am trying to read the Projection from GeoTIFF/shapefile, using GDAL 1.9.0 by the following command in the command line...

```
gdalinfo.exe -proj4 map-path
```

but its retuning empty string for "PROJECTION" parameter...  when I check the same map in QGIS getting the correct projection for this map.

Actually I want to retrieve "PROJECTION" value for any map from the C/C++ code, could you please let me know the way to retrieve this?

Comment: if it is a shapefile then you need to use ogrinfo

Comment: Yes, I have tried for a geotif file, for that its returning empty string, same thing is happening for shape file in ogriinfo as well.... I used the code to get the projection of the raster map in as in gdalinfo.c .             
        pszProjection = (char *) GDALGetProjectionRef( hDataset );

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that GDAL was installed in your Windows system with a procedure similar to this:

http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/

precisely one way to confirm successfully installation of GDAL is appealing to **gdalinfo --version** in a MS-DOS Console. By the way, I am using GDAL 1.10.1.

When I used a similar version of your command, for an arbitrary raster GTiff:

```
gdalinfo -proj4 c:/pyqgis_data/clip1.tif | find "proj"
```

I got this string:

```
'+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '
```

It worked well. I used a pipeline with **find** to filter by 'proj' because the default result of this command is too large.

Comment: Current Windows binaries for GDAL can be downloaded from http://www.gisinternals.com/. The current version is 1.11.1, and 1.11.2 is just around the corner.